# Removing the badge number when local notification is canceled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing a reminder app. I'm using local notification. It is working fine. But a badge number is always showing on top of my app's icon. How can I remove the badge number after firing the local notification? When I put `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;` in did finish launching, the badge number is completely removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to remove the `badgeNumber` from  the badge icon and show only an empty(without any number) badge icon.
You can not just remove the badge number alone from the badge icon. If you set `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to `0`, the badge icon itself will be removed from the application icon.

If the badge to be shown then there should be a number, not a `0`. `0` is inteneted to remove the badge icon.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever The Notification Fired In App delegate didReceiveLocalNotification Method Fired
You Can Decrease The Count By One And Add One When You Add New Notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=application.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

i try the same thing and i found this:

When the app in in the background and you try to set the LocalNotification to 0 it will not remove the IconBadgeNumber. you need to set the IconBadgeNumber to -1.

```
    UILocalNotification *localSilentNotif;
    localSilentNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```